# Create increasing vector

Tags: r

Starting from a vector, I want to remove elements, so that the remaining elements are increasing.
I already have an iterative approach that goes as follows:

```
test<- c(2,4,7,2,3,6,8)
while(!all(diff(test)>=0)){
    rm <- which(diff(test)<0)[1]+1
    if(!is.na(rm)) test<-test[-rm]
}
```

The expected output in my example would be (2,4,7,8).

Is there a smarter way to do it ?

EDIT: Added expected output of algorithm.

EDIT: Typo of output.

EDIT: Corrected my code so that it gives the desired result.

EDIT: Changed example to a more general one by adding 8 at the end.

Comment: The problem you state is underdefined. Could be (2,4,7), could be (2,3,6) and so on.

Comment: What is your desired output? I would have thought `c(2,4,7)`, but your code suggests something different. And it's not clear to me what you want if, say, `test <- c(2,4,7,2,3,6,9)`.

Comment: the output the code is giving is `c(2, 2, 3, 6)`

Comment: I still don't get the logic. Could you please explain?

Comment: @RonakShah I want an algorithm that discards the elements that make the vector not being increasing.

Comment: @Jcl: we got that. The problem is there are multiple valid solutions (e.g. if you remove `2,3,6` you get `2,4,7`, otherwise if you remove `4,7,2,3` you get `2,4,6`). We need to know which criteria are you using to decide `2,4,6` is the correct one...

Comment: @digEmAll I'm sorry there was a typo in my question, the goal is to remove 2,3,6 you get 2,4,7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering the output obtained with your code, I believe you want to remove the values that makes the numbers in your vector not increasing.

**EDIT2**

If you want to keep all increasing values, here is an option with `while`:

```
last_val <- test[1]
out_ind <- c(1)
i <- 2
while (i<=length(test)){
    if (test[i] >= last_val) {out_ind <- c(out_ind, i); last_val <- test[i]}
    i <- i+1
}
```

**EDIT1**

If you just want to remove numbers after the first not increasing one, you can go with @RHertel answer or `test[1:which(diff(test) < 0)[1]]` to avoid the warning message if there are multiples negative "diff" values.

**First answer with the expected output from your code**

here is a way to do it:

```
# get the indexes of the sorted vector
ot <- order(test) 
# then you remove the value that doesn't correspond to increasing indexes
test <- test[-ot[which(diff(ot)<0)+1]]
>test
#[1] 2 2 3 6
```

Comment: please can the person who downvoted argument the downvote ? I'm getting the output given by the OP's code and (imo) my code is doing what is asked

Comment: @Jcl This seems to be giving the output of your loop which is what you want according to your description.

Comment: I noticed a typo in my initial question, I am sorry about that.

Comment: Unfortunately, `test[1:which(diff(test) < 0)[1]]` fails for  `c(2,4,7,2,3,1,8)`, as I would expect the output to be (2,4,7,8).

Comment: @digEmAll I've edited my code with an option giving the (finally clear) output. I let you do the benchmark if you don't mind (and you want to)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this helps:

```
test[1:which(diff(test) < 0)]
#[1] 2 4 7
```

Comment: This fails: `test <- c(2,4,7,2,3,1)`

Comment: This will give a different answer to his code though. He will remove the first non-increasing element, then will go back through the list again, removing the next non-increasing element, continuing until the list is strictly increasing. This method will cut the list when it comes to the first non-increasing element. So his method will give 2, 4, 6 and yours will give 2, 4, 7.

Comment: My apologies, I admit that my question might not have been stated clear enough.  My goal is to remove the elements, in order to make the vector increasing.

Comment: This is not the correct code, try with this vector: `test <- c(2,4,7,2,3,9)` and you won't get `2,4,7,9`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't require `2 3 3 1 4` to yield `2 3 3 4` (i.e. equal to is not increasing) you can use a nice reduce

```
test <- c(2,4,7,2,3,1,8)
unique(Reduce(max, as.list(test), accumulate = TRUE))
 [1] 2 4 7 8
```

If you do want the repeats, I'm sure there's a nicer way to do this but

```
test <- c(2,4,4,7,2,3,1,8)
reduce = Reduce(max, as.list(test), accumulate = TRUE)
df = data.frame(o = test, reduce = reduce)
df[df$o == df$reduce, "o"]
 [1] 2 4 4 7 8
```

will pull them out.

Comment: This is great! I'm not really a functional programmer so I didn't even think to Reduce, but this is definitely the way to go. +1

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer I also found another way to do this, which basically boils down to your method, which is `unique(cummax(test))`

Comment: Oh awesome! Much better than mine, and presumably it's defined for matricies and data frames too.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a good old `for-loop`:

```
test <- c(2,4,7,2,3,9)

test2 <- rep(NA,length(test))
test2[1] <- test[1]
prev <- test[1]
for(i in 2:length(test)){
  if(prev < test[i]){
    test2[i] <- test[i]
    prev <- test[i]
  }
}
test2 <- test2[!is.na(test2)]

#> test2
#[1] 2 4 7 9
```

---

Benchmark:

```
makeIncreasing_digEmAll <- function(test){
  test2 <- rep(NA,length(test))
  test2[1] <- test[1]
  prev <- test[1]
  for(i in 2:length(test)){
    if(prev < test[i]){
      test2[i] <- test[i]
      prev <- test[i]
    }
  }
  test2 <- test2[!is.na(test2)]
  return(test2)
}

makeIncreasing_Jcl <- function(test){
  while(!all(diff(test)>=0)){
    rm <- which(diff(test)<0)[1]+1
    if(!is.na(rm)) test<-test[-rm]
  }
  return(test)
}


set.seed(123)
test2 <- runif(n=1000,min=1,max=10000)

timeDigEmAll <- system.time(for(i in 1:200)makeIncreasing_digEmAll(test2),gcFirst=T)
timeJcl <- system.time(for(i in 1:200)makeIncreasing_Jcl(test2),gcFirst=T)

> timeDigEmAll
   user  system elapsed 
   0.17    0.00    0.17 
> timeJcl
   user  system elapsed 
  29.80    0.02   30.28
```

Comment: I appreciate you help. (especially testing the answers above !) but I was able to make my algorithm, which uses a while loop, run.

Comment: Ok, I suggest you to post your own code as an answer so you can show us what's your solution ;)

Comment: Ok, I think your code has a worst complexity than mine `O(n^2) vs O(n)` have a look at the benchmark I added in my answer

Comment: (even if, of course, on small vectors you won't notice the difference...)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank everyone who has contributed to this discussion I have used digEmAll's code for benchmarking  and compared all the methods above. Here are the results.

```
makeIncreasing_digEmAll <- function(test){
        test2 <- rep(NA,length(test))
        test2[1] <- test[1]
        prev <- test[1]
        for(i in 2:length(test)){
                if(prev < test[i]){
                        test2[i] <- test[i]
                        prev <- test[i]
                }
        }
        test2 <- test2[!is.na(test2)]
        return(test2)
}

makeIncreasing_Jcl <- function(test){
        while(!all(diff(test)>=0)){
                rm <- which(diff(test)<0)[1]+1
                if(!is.na(rm)) test<-test[-rm]
        }
        return(test)
}

makeIncreasing_Jcl2 <- function(test){

        return(unique(cumsum(test)))
}

makeIncreasing_CathG <- function(test){
        last_val <- test[1]
        out_ind <- c(1)
        i <- 2
        while (i<=length(test)){
                if (test[i] >= last_val) {out_ind <- c(out_ind, i); last_val <- test[i]}
                i <- i+1
        }
        return(test)
}

set.seed(123)
test2 <- runif(n=1000,min=1,max=10000)

timeDigEmAll <- system.time(for(i in 1:200)makeIncreasing_digEmAll(test2),gcFirst=T)
timeJcl <- system.time(for(i in 1:200)makeIncreasing_Jcl(test2),gcFirst=T)
timeJcl2 <- system.time(for(i in 1:200)makeIncreasing_Jcl2(test2),gcFirst=T)
timeCathG <- system.time(for(i in 1:200)makeIncreasing_CathG(test2),gcFirst=T)



> timeDigEmAll
   user  system elapsed 
  0.068   0.000   0.068 
> timeJcl
   user  system elapsed 
  14.64    0.00   14.64 
> timeJcl2
   user  system elapsed 
  0.008   0.000   0.008 
> timeCathG
   user  system elapsed 
  0.124   0.000   0.124
```

In conclusion, `unique(cumsum(test))` is the way to go.